# Prestashop 1.6 order confirmation link

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a shop powered by Prestashop 1.6. I want to add new step to order creation. I want to add an unique link in the transactional email template, that confirms the order and change status of order. Is it possible to do this in this version of prestashop?

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop 1.6 doesn't support this feature, but you can create extend prestshop core to make it work

Comment: And does prestashop 1.7 support this future?

Comment: 1.7 doesnt support too